# Fastest way to do a contains with string[]

Tags: c#

I am getting back a "string[]" from a 3rd party library.  I want to do a contains on it.  what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array.IndexOf:

```
bool contains = Array.IndexOf(arr, value) >= 0;
```

Or just use LINQ:

```
bool contains = arr.Contains(value);
```

LINQ should be "fast enough" for most purposes.

Answer (score 7):

If you are only checking a single time, use `Array.IndexOf` or the LINQ Contains method like Marc proposed. If you are checking several times, it might be faster to first convert the string array into a `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: Good catch with HashSet; +1 ;-p

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know the String array is sorted by a particular order the most efficient thing you can do is linear algorithm (i.e. compare each string in the array until you find a match or the end of the array.

If the array is sorted a binary search is much faster.

Another way to optimize the algorithm (although the complexity is not reduced) is to vectorize the string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that a `for` loop is faster, if absolute speed is your concern. I.e.,

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
  if (arr[i] == value) return true;
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching once or twice, use a linear search or IndexOf.

If you're searching a few times, put the strings into a HashSet.

If you're searching zillions of times in a time-critical fashion, use a HashSet and manage its bucket count yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **IEnumerable.Foreach** Custom Extension

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable list, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] list = new String[] { "Word1", "Word2", "Word3" };

        list.ForEach<String>(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
        list.ForEach(delegate(String p) { Console.WriteLine(p); });
    }
}
```

Hope this help's.